# C - Graph - How to add root check for finding Articulation Points

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures, graph, adjacency-list

so basically I implemented a code to find articulation points in a graph, I'm using Adjacency List to implement the Graph. Everything works, except for the starting point. It's children is gonna have it's `low` same as the root's `num` so I need to add an extra condition: `if(low[w]>=num[v] && num[v] != 1)`. The `num[v] != 1` checks that were not comparing it with the root. I tried to play around it, because when I make the root an AP, it doesn't work, or it messes the whole thing up. Originally, the graph has only two AP, I made the root as the third to test if it works, but it doesn't, HELP ME.

So this works:

```
        if(num[v]==1 && root_check == 2)
        {
            printf("%d is an Articulation Point!!!\n", v);
        }
        if(low[w]>=num[v] && num[v] != 1)
        {
            printf("%d is an Articulation Point!!!\n", v);
        }
```

but this doesn't:

```
        if(low[w]>=num[v] || (num[v]==1 && root_check==2))
        {
            printf("%d is an Articulation Point!!!\n", v);
        }
```

Code:

```
void check_ap(struct Graph *G, int v)
{
    int root_check = 0;
    visited[v] = 1;
    low[v] = num[v] = counter++;
    struct VertexNode *adj = G->AdjListArr[v].head;
    while(adj)
    {
        if(num[v]==1){++root_check;}
        int w = adj->dest;
        if(!visited[w])
        {
            parent[w] = v;
            check_ap(G, w);
            if(num[v]==1 && root_check == 2)
            {
                printf("%d is an Articulation Point!!!\n", v);
            }
            if(low[w]>=num[v] && num[v] != 1)
            {
                printf("%d is an Articulation Point!!!\n", v);
            }
            low[v] = min(low[v], low[w]);
        }
        else
        {
            if(parent[v]!=w)
            {
                low[v] = min(low[v], low[w]);
            }
        }
        
        adj=adj->next;
    }
    
}
```

Also, why does `3 is an Articulation Point!!!` appear twice??

OUTPUT:

```
3 is an Articulation Point!!!
3 is an Articulation Point!!!
0 is an Articulation Point!!!
1 is an Articulation Point!!!
```

Comment: Missing 'num[v] != 1'?

Comment: @tstanisl Yep `if((low[w]>=num[v] && num[v]!=1) || (num[v]==1 && root_check==2))` fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Expression `&& num[v] != 1` is missing that was present in the second condition.